# Jdeveloper run configurations missing in version 11.1.2.2.0

Tags: ide, jdeveloper

Just wondering if anyone else has experienced problems with JDeveloper 11.1.2.2.0 and run configuration options that appear when you click the dropdown next to the run and debug buttons?

In previous versions I always had several options available - for starting the client/server/etc. However in this version I do not always get the dropdown unless I click into a different project, then click back into the project I want to run. If anyone has discovered a more permanent fix for this I would love to hear about it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug I also stumbled upon. Only other thing you can try is to use the run menu and check if you see the options in there.

I personally use trick you already know (switching projects).

Comment: Yeah, guess that will have to do for now at least :(